# Is Chi square appropriate to show one set of binary data comes from a different population than another set of binary data?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, binary-data

I am comparing the accuracy of different computer programs on making predictions on the same set of data inputs. For example each of 5 computer programs read in the same 100 data points, and make a prediction for each of those data points, thus each program makes 100 predictions. The predictions are then categorized into Correct or Incorrect.

I want to show one or more programs is significantly better or worse at making predictions than the rest. I know multi variable chi square tests seem reasonable, but my problem is I would be trying to prove the null hypothesis, that there is no relationship. I am not sure if that reduces my power, I'm not well versed in statistics. Is there a better test for this or does a multi variable chi square test make sense?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You say "the predictions are then categorized into Correct and Incorrect". Is it possible to compare -- meaningfully -- the raw predictions? For example, if the models predict probability of an event, then you can evaluate the probabilistic predictions directly. If that's possible, you might be able to make a more in-depth evaluation that a chi-squared test on the proportion of correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's good you realized that the 'research' hypothesis
in a chi-squared test is sometimes the null. You might want
to see of five computer programs are equally good at
prediction, that there is no difference in quality
between new and old methods of production, or that four
groups of mice match the same genetic model for fur color.

A variant of a chi-squared test of homogeneity for
equal proportions is `prop.test` in R. It might
present the estimated Proportions Correct in a more
convenient way for your experiment.

Suppose that
the five programs had $(55,62,73,82,81)$ successes, respectively,
out of 100, then `prop.test` provides the output below, rejecting
$H_0$ that all five are equally successful at any reasonable level
because of the P-value near $0.$ (By doing *post hoc* tests you
could explore which programs are significantly different from
which others)

```
prop.test(c(55,62,73,82,81), rep(100,5))

        5-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(55, 62, 73, 82, 81) out of rep(100, 5)
X-squared = 27.037, df = 4, p-value = 1.954e-05
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 prop 3 prop 4 prop 5 
  0.55   0.62   0.73   0.82   0.81
```

By contrast, if successes out of 100 are $(55,62,63,67,70),$
then no differences are found among the five programs at the 5% level of significance;
P-value $0.2338 > 0.05 = 5\%.$

```
prop.test(c(55,62,63,67,70), rep(100,5))

        5-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(55, 62, 63, 67, 70) out of rep(100, 5)
X-squared = 5.5679, df = 4, p-value = 0.2338
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
 prop 1 prop 2 prop 3 prop 4 prop 5 
   0.55   0.62   0.63   0.67   0.70
```

In R, `chisq.test` requires that data be presented as a table,
but the chi-squared statistic and the P-value are the same as above.

```
succ = c(55, 62, 63, 67, 70)
fail = 100 - succ

TBL = rbind(succ, fail);  TBL
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
succ   55   62   63   67   70
fail   45   38   37   33   30

chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 5.5679, df = 4, p-value = 0.2338
```

Comment: I interpret the request in the question a little differently.  `prop.test` "can be used for testing the null that the proportions (probabilities of success) in several groups are ... equal certain given values," as per its help page.  But that differs subtly from "one or more ... is significantly better or worse ... than the rest."  It is possible for the data to indicate this alternative holds, but for there to be no significant evidence of superiority or inferiority by any group. Then there's the issue of *pairing:* we should expect the results to be correlated, not independent.

Comment: Wording of the the help page notwithstanding, it seems clear that `prop.test` and `chisq.test` are doing exactly the same thing: same chi-sq statistic and same P-value. So, are you saying that neither test answers your interpretation of the current question? Or something else that I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, that's correct: I understand `prop.test` is performing a chi-squared test whose null is $H_0:p_1=p_2=\cdots=p_5.$  I am questioning whether that correctly responds to the question being asked here.